# Calling Multiple component in same page in React.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux

I am creating a react main page which is rendering two react component as

```
render() {
    return (
        <Header />             
        <Test />
    );
}
```

Header is having simple static content.In Test I am calling external api using redux on page page load as

```
componentWillMount() {
    if (this.props.onPageLoadTest) {
        this.props.onPageLoadTest();
    }
}
render() {
    const { data } = this.props;
    return (
        <div>
            {
                data.map((a) => (

                    <div key={a.id}>{a.id}

                    </div>

                ))
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Using props I am showing content in Test component.Header and Test are working fine when I am rendering them separately.
When I am trying to combine then only Header is showing but Test is not able to fetch data from API.

Comment: Does the help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33922015/reactjs-how-create-two-or-more-components-in-same-page

Comment: If I add anything static in Test it is working but 'data' which is coming from API becomes null.

Comment: Show your `main` component here

Comment: Did you try wrapping both the components inside a `<div></div>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do things like this:

```
render() {
    return (
        <Header />             
        <Test />
    );
}
```

there can be only one markup in the `return` of `render()`

if you want to render the Header and Test together here, you have to wrap them with one markup,like this:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Header />             
            <Test />
        </div>
    );
}
```